# A way to see what command exactly sshd executes?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

I was thinking of passing an environment variable to a command over ssh:

```
$ ssh HOST A=1 set | grep ^A
$ ssh HOST A=1 sh -c set | grep ^A
A='1'
$ ssh HOST A=1 echo '$A'
$ ssh HOST A=1 sh -c 'echo $A'
```

So, `set` doesn't see the environment variable, but it does in a separate process. The same doesn't seem to happen with `echo`.

Is there a way to find out what exactly is sent, and how exactly it's executed (which command `sshd` launches)?

Comment: What does the `echo` return for you?

Comment: `ssh -v …` will tell you the command string being sent; but it won't tell you what exact shell is used on the remote side to execute it. It's possible to get the information about the shell from within the shell, but you need to preassume something about the shell (e.g. that the shell is `sh`-compatible). From your commands (or from `ssh -v …`) it's possible to tell what command string the remote shell got in each case; and (assuming `sh`-compatibility) to explain why the commands worked like they worked. But I don't think you can know the remote shell without assuming anything.

Comment: One way or another, `sshd` invokes a shell to run the command string you send it (or an interactive login one if no command is supplied). Are you interested how exactly `sshd` invokes that shell or in how that shell executes the command you send over SSH?

Comment: @rage Only one command produced output, the `echo` commands outputted nothing.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `ssh -v` might already be good enough, thanks for the tip. To make it more usable, `ssh -v HOST CMD |& grep 'Sending command'`. I generally more or less know which shell is on the other side. Usually it's `sh` or `bash`. Although if you can elaborate on how `sshd` chooses the shell, that would be welcome.

Comment: @fra-san Rather in how `sshd` invokes the shell. If I know what exactly is sent, and which shell executes it, than I have enough to either send a correct command right away, or correct it, if I made an error. That's the goal.

Comment: @x-yuri Thank you. There are a few close votes as "Needs details or clarity" on this question, so I think you should try to edit it and add the information you provided in your comments. Also, you may make clear if you have issues with the shown commands (e.g. are you getting unexpected results? If so, which results were you expecting?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `ssh user@host command`, the tokens resulting from the expansion of `command` are concatenated by `ssh` with a space in between and sent as a string to the remote host. The remote host then executes an instance of the remote user's default shell (the one specified in `/etc/passwd`), passing the string it received from the client as the argument to the shell's `-c` option (more on this below).

So, for instance, in

```sh
$ foo="bar    baz"
$ ssh user@host echo "$foo"
bar baz
```

the local `ssh` receives the two arguments `echo` and `bar    baz`. It concatenates them to form the string `echo bar    baz` and sends it to the server. The server executes something along the lines of `/bin/sh -c 'echo bar    baz'` and the output of this command is printed on the local `ssh`'s standard output.

How can you see what the client actually sends to the server?

As [Kamil Maciorowski pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/600882/a-way-to-see-what-command-exactly-sshd-executes#comment1121962_600882) in a comment to the question, `ssh -v` outputs as a debug message the command string being sent to the server:

```
$ ssh -v host A=1 sh -c set | grep ^A
...
debug1: Sending command: A=1 sh -c set
...
```

How can you see what `sshd` actually executes?

I am not aware of any way to request the server to show the client some kind of trace of its own operations. But, for testing purposes, you can `strace` an instance of the daemon:

```sh
$ sudo strace -e execve -f /usr/bin/sshd -p 2222
```

This is especially useful because it is easy not to get the quoting right when composing a command line for remote execution. Take, for instance (a variation on the examples provided in your question):

```sh
$ ssh -p 2222 host bash -c 'A=1 set'
                                        # Prints nothing
```

`strace` reveals that what we may see as a command string is actually split on the remote host, which first runs the full command line in the user's default shell (the single quotes have been removed by the local shell when it built the argument list for `ssh`):

```
... execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "bash -c A=1 set"] ...
```

and then:

```
... execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "A=1", "set"] ...
```

Note how the command string (the argument to `-c`) happens to be just `A=1`. `set` is passed to `bash` as the zeroth argument (available as `$0` and used as the command name).

How to see what the remote shell actually executes?

Again, I am not aware of any easy way. In simple cases, the use of the shell's `xtrace` option is straightforward. For instance, `ssh host A=1 set` may become:

```sh
$ command=$(printf '%s ' A=1 set); printf '%s\n' "${command% }" |
  ssh host sh -x
```

`sh` should be replaced with the remote user's default shell.

The command is piped to `ssh`'s standard input because this form allows for typing it unchanged (`ssh host sh -xc A=1 set` won't work for the reason shown above and adding quoting would defeat, to some extent, the very purpose of this exercise).

In less simple cases, especially when the the `ssh` invocation you are digging into already makes use of standard input, you may force the remote host to run a shell with `xtrace` turned on. **For experimenting purposes, and having clear that errors may make you unable to log in to the remote system**, a (rather sketchy) way could be to replace the remote user's default shell in `/etc/passwd`. Assuming it was `/bin/sh`, change it into `/home/your_user/bin/sh` and create the latter as an executable script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/sh -x "$@"
```

Which will make the shell show you a trace of what is being executed:

```sh
$ ssh host A=1 echo foo
foo
+ A=1
+ echo foo
```

Finally, about your sample commands:

- The reason `ssh HOST A=1 set` doesn't print `A=1` is likely that your user's default shell is Bash (possibly invoked as `sh`). Contrary to what happens in `dash`, `ksh`, `yash`, `zsh`, `set` in Bash (at least the version I have, `5.0.17`) does not output the variables set *for the `set` command itself*. On the other hand, you could probably confirm that:

  ```sh
  $ ssh host 'A=1
  > set' | grep ^A
  A=1
  ```

  I.e. `A` is shown in `set`'s output if it is declared before `set` is invoked.
- In `A=1 sh -c set`, `A` is added to the environment of `sh` and is thus unsurprisingly printed by `set`.
- `A=1 echo '$A'` doesn't print the value of `A` because `A` is only added to the environment for the execution of `echo` (assuming it is built-in), after the expansion of `$A`. Compare it with `ssh host 'A=1; echo $A'`, which prints `1`.
- `A=1 sh -c 'echo $A'` prints nothing because, as shown above, the remote host executes the remote user's default shell with the `-c` option and `A=1 sh -c echo $A` as its argument, and then that shell runs `sh -c echo $A`: the command string ends up being just `echo`, with no arguments.

  To make it work you need to make sure the quotes around `echo $A` are sent to the remote host *and* `$A` is protected from being expanded too early (by the local shell or by the "outer" remote one): e.g. `ssh host A=1 sh -c '"echo \$A"'` or `ssh host A=1 sh -c "'echo \$A'"`.

  When explicitly calling a remote shell, it is probably easier to make it read commands from standard input:

  ```sh
  $ echo 'echo $A' | ssh host A=1 sh -s
  1
  ```

#### See also

- [How do ssh remote command line arguments get parsed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414636/315749)
- [Quoting in ssh $host $FOO and ssh $host "sudo su user -c $FOO" type constructs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4770/315749)