# Variable expansion with sh -c executed over ssh

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, variable

I'm trying to execute an command via sh -c over SSH in an LXC container. Since lxc-attach is involved I have to use `sh -c` like this: `ssh <host> "lxc-attach -- sh -c \"<command>;<command>\""`. This works for most cases. But when I try to use a literal  environment variable in the command, the variable keeps expanding.

The problem  can be simplified to this: I want to print a literal `$HOME`

**Local:**

```
user@local:~$ sh -c 'echo $HOME'
/home/user
# Despite single quote the variable gets expanded, one has to escape the $ sign
user@local:~$ sh -c 'echo \$HOME'
$HOME
```

So far so good, but when I try this over SSH **remote**:

```
user@local:~$ ssh remote "sh -c 'echo \$HOME'"
/root
user@local:~$ ssh remote 'sh -c 'echo \$HOME''

user@local:~$ ssh remote "sh -c \'echo \$HOME\'"
/root': 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I tried serveral variants of escaping the variable. It keeps expanding, nothing is printed or an error appears.

Comment: See the paragraph named "Discussion" and the procedure in the paragraph named "Solution" in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1534401/432690). Also this: [*How can I single-quote or escape the whole command line in Bash conveniently?*](https://superuser.com/q/1531395/432690)

Comment: Thanks, the last one is very useful

Comment: See also [How to execute an arbitrary simple command over ssh without knowing the login shell of the remote user?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/205567)

Answer (score 2):

SSH always runs a shell on remote to process the command line you give.
See:  [How do ssh remote command line arguments get parsed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414636/170373)

```
$ ssh remote "sh -c 'echo \$HOME'"
/root
```

The local shell undoes one layer of quotes, turning `\$` into `$`
SSH sends `sh -c 'echo $HOME'` to the remote for running in a shell, and the `sh` you explicitly start expands `$HOME`.

```
$ ssh remote 'sh -c 'echo \$HOME''
```

This is the same as

```
$ ssh remote 'sh -c echo' \$HOME              # or
$ ssh remote 'sh -c echo' '$HOME'
```

Note that the space is unquoted (and the `echo` in the original, but that doesn't matter).

SSH joins the arguments it gets with spaces, and then sends the string `sh -c echo $HOME` to the remote. The resulting command passed via `-c` to the inner shell is just the command `echo`. The expansion of `$HOME` goes in `$0` of that inner `sh`.

```
$ ssh remote "sh -c \'echo \$HOME\'"
/root': 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Here, the local shell  again turns `\$` into `$`, and SSH sends the string
`sh -c \'echo $HOME\'` to the remote, where the shell started by SSH parses those backslashes and runs the command `sh` with the arguments `-c`, `'echo`, `/home/username'` (expanding `$HOME`). The *inner* `sh` sees the command `'echo` which indeed has an unterminated quoted string.

You'd need something like this

```
$ ssh localhost 'sh -c "echo \\\$HOME"'
$HOME
```

to protect the expansion from both the local shell (single quotes above), the shell started by SSH (backslashes), and the shell you started with `sh -c` (another level of backslashes, one for `\`, one for `$`).

Or with single quotes instead of one layer of backslashes:

```
$ ssh localhost 'sh -c '\''echo \$HOME'\'
$HOME
```

It's easier to pass the command through a file or a (quoted) here-doc, or some such:

```
$ ssh localhost 'sh -s' <<'EOF'
echo '$HOME'
EOF
$HOME
```

See also: [Quoting in ssh $host $FOO and ssh $host "sudo su user -c $FOO" type constructs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4770/170373)